# NGINX: rewrite rules to pass two parameters?

Tags: http, nginx

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to have clean URLs to simply pass parameters.

the first line works, the second line does NOT. I want to have something like

`example.com/11/22` to be interpreted as `/index.php?project=11&entry=12`

here my code in nginx server config

```
rewrite ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-_\s]+)$ /index.php?project=$1 last; //this WORKS
rewrite ^/([0-9a-zA-Z-_\s]+)$/([0-9a-zA-Z-_\s]+)$ /index.php?project=$1&item=$2 last;
```

Comment: There's a `$` in the middle of the regex that should not be there. `^` and `$` are anchors for the start and end of a string and have no business in the middle.